# What is this History menu option in the menu bar and how do I clear it?

Tags: macos, history

[image]

Between the menu options **Edit** and **View** and sometimes between **View** and **Go** appears, when you open a web browser, another menu option named **History** that show all the recent browsing history.

How do I clear it when it appears? How do I delete the items that appear or, even better, only a selection of them?

Comment: Based on the contents of your Dock, I presume you are referring to Safari. Please re-edit your question to clarify if this is not the case.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Which app? Can you add another screenshot with the history tab there? The only other thing I can think of that you may be getting confused with is when you click the view tab...

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are referring to Safari. The option appears when Safari is the front application.

[image]

You can clear Safari's history by going to **History** → **Clear History**….

[image]

To clear a certain section of history rather than the entire history, press ⌥⌘2, select the rows you wish to delete and press ⌫.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no! It's not the history tab of the internet it's a tab called "history" in the apple tallbar that shows everything- which things you opened in your computer and also in the internet. for instense, if you open the safari history and closed it- it will show under tha apple tab history the word "history". It will show that you looked at your safari history.

Comment: @user77854 Finder doesn't have a history tab — per my above comment please clarify your question with a screenshot of what you're *actually* referring to. I've rolled back my edit regarding Safari.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is, in fact, the history from the web browser. Presumably Safari in your case. Finder itself doesn't have a 'History' menu option. And in your question you say "appears (when you open a web browser)" and that's the key bit of information.

The menu bar in OS X is shared among all applications. What is shown in the menu bar, that thin bar that runs along the top of your screen, changes depending on which application is in the foreground. The position of the menu bar never changes: it's always at the top of the screen. ***But the menu items in the menu bar change depending on what application is in the foreground.***

For example, when Finder is in the foreground I see:

[image]

And when I switch to Safari I see:

[image]

Similarly with Chrome in the foreground I see:

[image]

So that 'History' item menu you're referring to is the browsing history for whatever browser you happen to be using. To clear the browsing history for...

Safari:

From the menu bar select: **History > Clear History...**

Chrome:

Press Cmd-Y to open the History tab in Chrome and click the `Clear browsing data...` button on that page.

Firefox:

Click the menu button and select **History > Clear Recent History....**